# GDB command to print the address of starting of buffer (stack)

Tags: gdb, stack

For gdb debugger

```
(gdb) p &buffer
```

This command is used to print the content of starting of buffer (stack), or print the address?

If it is content, how to print the address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what type the `buffer` is.

Most likely `buffer` is a pointer to the start of the buffer. The C-style declaration for it might be `struct stackElement *buffer;` or something similar (note the asterisk!).
In that case:

- `p &buffer` prints the address where the pointer itself is stored (i.e. "the address of the address of the buffer")
- `p buffer` should print the value of the `buffer` pointer variable, which is the address of the buffer.
- `p *buffer` should print the contents of the buffer.

If `buffer`is some structure type, and not a pointer (example C declaration might be `struct stackElement buffer;` with no asterisk), then:

- `p &buffer` prints the address where the structure is, i.e. the address of the buffer
- `p buffer` prints the contents of this structure (= if this is a stack, probably the first stack element)
- `p *buffer` is an error.